# How is my list_display and list_editable clashing?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin, changelist

When I started building this project, it went pretty smoothly. But when I reached the admin, list_display and list_editable clashed:

admin.py Code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article, Author

# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
@admin.register(Author)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'join_date', 'email']
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name[0]}"
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    join_date = models.DateField()
    participated_art = models.ManyToManyField('Article', blank=True)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_of_publication = models.DateField()
    creaters = models.ManyToManyField('Author', blank=False)
    main_txt = models.TextField()
    notes = models.TextField()
```

Error Code:

```
Exception in thread Django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\PycharmProjects\djangoProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\PycharmProjects\djangoProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\PycharmProjects\djangoProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 546, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'CodeJangoHome.admin.ArticleAdmin'>: (admin.E124) The value of 'list_editable[0]' refers to the first field in 'list_display' ('title'), which cannot be used unless 'list_display_links' is set.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

After I read the error, as shown above, I tried adding `list_display_links = ['title', 'main_txt']` into the code:

```
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

But it didn't work out the way it was supposed to. I got another error, that was between `list_display_links` and `list_editable`:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\PycharmProjects\djangoProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\PycharmProjects\djangoProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Zhiyue\PycharmProjects\djangoProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 546, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'CodeJangoHome.admin.ArticleAdmin'>: (admin.E123) The value of 'title' cannot be in both 'list_editable' and 'list_display_links'.
<class 'CodeJangoHome.admin.ArticleAdmin'>: (admin.E123) The value of 'main_txt' cannot be in both 'list_editable' and 'list_display_links'.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

So, with list_display, list_editable, and list_display_links, I have a problem fitting them into the code in admin.py.I don't exactly know how to use them so a bit of help would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django automatically set the first column of `list_display` as a link to the change form.

You can either add another column (recommended), like

```
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

or explicitly set `list_display_links` to `None`

```
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
    list_display_links = None
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

EDIT:

It is not required to put `__str__` in `list_display`. It is just the first column of `list_display` that makes it special: Django automatically convert it to a link, if not specified.

PS: What can be used in `list_display`?

According to [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display),

1. A field of model.
2. A callable.
3. A string representing a ModelAdmin attribute.
4. A string representing a model attribute.

Example `list_display`s:

```
@admin.display(descriptor='Title')
def upper_case_title(obj):
    return obj.title.upper()

@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__str__', 'title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    # 1. list_display = ['id', 'title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    # 2. list_display = ['article_title', 'title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    # 3. list_display = ['__str__', 'title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    # 4. list_display = ['id_title', 'title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

To implement 4. you need to modify model definition

```
#models.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_of_publication = models.DateField()
    creaters = models.ManyToManyField('Author', blank=False)
    main_txt = models.TextField()
    notes = models.TextField()

    @admin.display(descriptor='Title')
    def id_title(self):
        return f'{self.id}. {self.title}'
```

Again, I am just giving examples, you are not required to code exactly as above.

Comment: Why do I need to put the __str__ function in the list_display list?

Comment: I am using `__str__` just to avoid `title` being the column, and you can use other fields, callables, methods, too. I will edit my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

According to django documentation. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/)

> - Any field in `list_editable` must also be in `list_display`. You can’t edit a field that’s not displayed!
> - The same field can’t be listed in both `list_editable` and `list_display_links` – a field can’t be both a form and a link.

So in `list_display_links` you should have a different field from those in `list_editable`

Answer (score 0):

You got the error below:

> ERRORS:
> <class 'CodeJangoHome.admin.ArticleAdmin'>: (admin.E124) The
> value of 'list_editable[0]' refers to the first field in
> 'list_display' ('title'), which cannot be used unless
> 'list_display_links' is set.

Because by default, **the 1st column "title"** is **link** unless you set [list_display_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) and you tried to make the link editable by assigning it to [list_editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) which is impossible to make the link editable:

```py
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
                     # ↓ Link
    list_display = ['title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
                      # ↑ Tries to make the link editable but impossible
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And, you got the errors below:

> ERRORS:
> <class 'CodeJangoHome.admin.ArticleAdmin'>:
> (admin.E123) The value of 'title' cannot be in both 'list_editable'
> and 'list_display_links'.
> <class 'CodeJangoHome.admin.ArticleAdmin'>: (admin.E123) The
> value of 'main_txt' cannot be in both 'list_editable' and
> 'list_display_links'.

Because you assigned `'title'` and `'main_txt'` to both `list_editable` and `list_display_links` as shown below which is impossible that a column is both **link** and **editable**:

```py
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
                      # ↑Here↓    ↑Here↓ Impossible  
    list_display_links = ['title', 'main_txt']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

So to solve your errors, add `list_display_links = ['date_of_publication']` as shown below to disable **link** for **the 1st column "title"** and to enable **link** for **the 3rd column "date_of_publication"** as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
    list_display_links = ['date_of_publication'] # Here
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Or, add `list_display_links = None` to disable **link** for **the 1st column "title"** as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'main_txt', 'date_of_publication']
    list_editable = ['title', 'main_txt']
    list_display_links = None # Here
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```